# how can i duplicate Prestashop 1.6 back office page (AdminOrdersController)

Tags: controller, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, backoffice

I am trying to create a different view for **AdminOrdersController** but keep also the default one.

I can't find any step by step tutorial to do this by my self.

Comment: Why don't you create a new controller? How are you going to switch between one view and another?

Comment: @joseantgv OK let me know how can i create new one with the same view!. then i can change some of row by my self.